# Get the rank of a user in a score table

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I have a simple MySQL table where I save the score of play. It looks like that:

```
**Id  -  UserId  -  Score**
```

The question is: How do I get what's a users rank? I have a users Id

An Example

```
**Id - UserId - Score**

1 - AAAA - 150

2 - BBBB - 110

3 - BBBB - 120

4 - CCCC - 102

5 - AAAA - 130
```

In this very case, IdUser CCCC rank would be 3, because he got the 3rd highest score.

The query should return one row, which contains (only) the required Rank.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have a user id, you want to return the number of users that have the same or greater score.

```
select count(*) as `rank`
from table t join
     (select score from table t where userId = @USERID) var
     on t.score >= var.score;
```

If you have duplicate scores, you might really want:

```
select 1 + count(*) as `rank`
from table t join
     (select score from table t where userId = @USERID) var
     on t.score > var.score;
```

It is unclear what you want with duplicate users.  I might suggest:

```
select 1 + count(*) as `rank`
from (select userId, max(score) as score
      from table t
      group by userId
     ) t join
     (select max(score) from table t where userId = @USERID) var
     on t.score > var.score;
```

Comment: If i have duplicate UserId like the example it doesn't work. The query for UserId CCCC return me rank position 4 instead 3

Comment: thanks but it gave me error
"Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: now another error :(
Unknown column 't.score' in 'on clause'

Comment: I need to know the user's position rank without considering all the possible records with duplicate UserId